# Free Php Library to get Graphs i.e Pie Chart / Bar Chart via MySql

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to make a pie chart where the data will be fetched from the database i.e MySql. I checked few like charts4php etc but are they available freely ? Can anyone just guide me for it ! 
Thank You

Comment: **Can anyone just guide me for it !** We're not the guide for you :(

Comment: You can just use mySql/PHP as your storage of data,but rendering pie charts, it faster to use javascript - > sample -> d3.js, highcharts,googlecharts, I hope this will help.

Comment: I just want to know which are freely available libraries nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts is a good option for you. You can just call the PHP within the javascript function:

```
<?php
$query = "
      SELECT someValue 
      FROM table_name 
      ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
//loop database results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[] = $row['price'];
}
?>
<script>
...snip...
//add a join function to separate each result with a comma
data: [<?php echo join($data, ', '); ?>]
</script>
```

In this example the X-axis is under `Categories: '';` and the Y-axis is `data: '';`  Here's a fiddle, it doesn't include PHP since it's not supported, but should give you an idea how to use highcharts.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5fcjv61/